# Not able to deploy project on docker on linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, docker, deployment

I am trying to deploy a project on docker which was earlier running on Mac. Now I am trying to deploy it on linux.

I am getting error starting  port.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint project_image (d364404a87be4c3453101d7): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 172.18.0.1:8080: bind: cannot assign requested address.
```

I have added this in my hosts file as well which I used to do in Mac for deploying docker.

I am new to docker and moreover I couldn't find any docker desktop for linux as well.

```
ranjeet@casper:~/project/ec2/docker$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

# Custom

172.18.0.1 project.dev api.project.dev api-offload.project.dev
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Below is the output of `sudo lsof -nP | grep LISTEN` on both MAC and Linux system:

*MAC*

```
com.docke  682          ranjeet   76u     IPv4 0xcfa23aa9f9c8387b        0t0     TCP 172.18.0.1:5001 (LISTEN)
com.docke  682          ranjeet   77u     IPv4 0xcfa23aa9f9c8549b        0t0     TCP 172.18.0.1:22 (LISTEN)
com.docke  682          ranjeet   78u     IPv4 0xcfa23aa9f2f7db3b        0t0     TCP 172.18.0.1:8080 (LISTEN)
```

*Linux*

```
docker-pr 18185                   root    4u     IPv6             155176       0t0        TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 18185 18186             root    4u     IPv6             155176       0t0        TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 18185 18187             root    4u     IPv6             155176       0t0        TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 18185 18188             root    4u     IPv6             155176       0t0        TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 18185 18189             root    4u     IPv6             155176       0t0        TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 18185 18190             root    4u     IPv6             155176       0t0        TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: How are you launching the container?  Where does that IP address come from?  (Directly using the container-private IP addresses isn't a good idea in general, and more specifically it doesn't work on MacOS.)

Comment: I think that IP came from combining project with front end. Actually using this same steps I was able to run docker locally on Mac. It's basically a dev env running on docker locally.

Comment: Please add the information what `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` or `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` outputs. There is a possibilty that another process is already using this port (e. g. `lighttpd`)

Comment: I tried this and compared both MAC and linux `sudo lsof -nP | grep LISTEN`. The problem which I face is actually that linux doesn't assign 172.18.0.1 to docker. Has included the output in question.

Comment: Okay, in this case, please also add the command you use to startup the container.

Comment: @agentsmith container is started using docker run script which is pre-written along with disable web. `DISABLE_WEB=1 ./docker-run.sh ~/project/ `